# send array with input file value

Tags: javascript, php

Good Day
I send an array from javascript that contains an image of a file type input,I need to know how to handle that array in php.
the array I get is type:

[image]

my php code is

```
<?php       
$data = json_decode($_POST["data"],true);      
print_r($data);
```

my javascript code is

```
         let warranty = {};
          warranty.description = document.getElementById("txt_description").value;
          warranty.brand = document.getElementById("txt_marca").value;
          warranty.serie = document.getElementById("txt_serie").value;
          warranty.model = document.getElementById("txt_model").value;
          warranty.color = document.getElementById("txt_color").value;
          warranty.time_use = document.getElementById("txt_year_use").value;
          warranty.status = document.getElementById("dp_status").value;
          warranty.location = document.getElementById("dp_location").value;
          warranty.price = document.getElementById("txt_price").value;
          warranty.img = imgInput.files[0];
          warranties.push(warranty);
          let datos = new FormData();
         datos.append("data",JSON.stringify(warranties));`
```

i tried

```
$img = $data[0]['img']; 
$file = $_FILES[$img]['tmp_name'];
```

but it sends me error index not found

Comment: Have you done a var_dump($_FILES); to see what you do have? Wheres the code to upload the files?

Answer (score 1):

File objects cannot be stringified to JSON. You need to append them directly to your `FormData` object.

You probably should forget about involving JSON entirely and then do something along the lines of:

```
const datos = new FormData();
warranties.forEach((warranty, index) => {
    Object.entries(warranty).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        datos.append(`data[${index}][${key}]`, value);
    });
});
```

Then the files will appear in `$_FILES` and the rest of the data in `$_POST`.